# Qt get language name in its native form

Tags: qt, globalization, qlocale

I'm adding language support into a Qt C++ application currently using QLocale and QTranslator. When the user selects the language from the settings menu, I want to show them the Language name in the native form (e.g. Deutsch instead of German), but when given a locale code QLocale returns the name as per the current locale (i.e. English).

Is there a way I can get the language name in native form using QLocale or something else in Qt which I've missed.

Comment: `QLocale::nativeLanguageName`, see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlocale.html#nativeLanguageName

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, looked like I missed that one. I'm now `QLocale::nativeLanguageName` on a `QLocale` object create using the locale name from the translation files I have.